# My code isn't writing to a new line in the csv file but is rather writing on the same line next to it

Tags: python, csv, writer

```
import csv 
with open ('database1.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    linetowrite = username + "," + password + "," + dob + "," +\
                  favartist + "," + favgenre
    csvfile.write(linetowrite)
csvfile.close()
```

That is my code, all the inputs are ok but there seems to be something wrong with that, can you help me?

Comment: You don't need to the `csvfile.close()` in the end as you're using a `with` block...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article and make edits to your question accordingly. You are not providing examples of the output you would expect, and are simply asking us to debug your code. This is not what Stack Overflow is intended for, we are here to help with specific problems you are facing, not provide general debugging or guidance.

Comment: Also does anyone know how to write over an input in the file?

Comment: @Pythonneeds as I said bellow, can you please make this question clearer and include it in your original question with an edit. For example, you might want to ask "how can I write over an existing line?", which would also raise the question of how to find the line you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Change `csvfile.write(linetowrite)` to `csvfile.write(linetowrite + "\n")`. This adds a newline character.

Comment: Although this trick works, it's not exactly making use of the very useful `csv` module that's being imported at the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the `csv` module but never actually using it. To do so, you would need to create a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer) like this:

```
import csv

with open('database1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvfilewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvfilewriter.writerow([username, password, dob, favartist, favgenre])
```